# Executing code when a list elements become active

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following HTML:

```
<ul class="tabs">
   <li id="taba" class="active"><a href="#a">A</a></li>
   <li><a id="tabb" href="#b">B</a></li>
   <li><a id="tabc" href="#c">C</a></li>
   <li><a id="tabd" href="#d">D</a></li>
</ul>
```

where one of the list elements `li` is active.  The HTML is represent a set of tabs.

I want to execute some jquery code when the user has switched tabs i.e. when the `class="active"` changes from one `li` to another.

How do you do this?

Comment: How do the tabs work? Are you listening for a `click` event or similar?

Comment: Obviously you somehow have to listen for events. Why don't you execute your code at the listener part?

Comment: They work using Twitter's CSS/Javascript bootstrap library.  You id the <a> tags and then use <div> tags for the content: <div id="my-tab-content" class="tab-content"> <div class="tab-pane" id="a"> ...

Answer (score 1):

in the [bootstrap tab documentation](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#tabs) you'll find the following code snippet

```
$('#tabs').bind('change', function (e) {
  e.target        // activated tab
  e.relatedTarget // previous tab
});
```